# Smooth Page Scroll - First click scrolls to wrong position. Second link works just fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, smooth-scrolling

Using [CSS Tricks Smooth Page Scroll](https://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/) code, and we just noticed, when you click on a navigation link for the first time, it scrolls down, but not to the point that it should, ~ 700px above intended section. Any subsequent clicks work just fine, it's the very first navigation click that's strange.

I've tried window.load instead, as I've read that all of the page elements may not have loaded by the time the user makes the first click, but that didn't help.

jQuery Version: 1.12.4/jquery.min.js

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have the same, what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to recreate the issue you are describing. The smooth scrolling is going to the corresponding section on your page.